# i want to make custom json from multiple json object

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

heres my first json

```
[
  {
    "future_sell": "2300.00",
    "to_currency": "DKK",
    "creation_datetime": "2016-10-20 12:23:29",
    "title": "Total selling currency",
    "title_two": "Date : 2016-10-20",
    "description": "DKK = 2300.00",
    "start": "2016-10-20",
    "end": "2016-10-20"
  },
  {
    "future_sell": "536.66",
    "to_currency": "USD",
    "creation_datetime": "2016-10-20 15:27:36",
    "title": "Total selling currency",
    "title_two": "Date : 2016-10-20",
    "description": "USD = 536.66",
    "start": "2016-10-20",
    "end": "2016-10-20"
  },
  {
    "future_sell": "600.00",
    "to_currency": "USD",
    "creation_datetime": "2016-10-21 13:51:28",
    "title": "Total selling currency",
    "title_two": "Date : 2016-10-21",
    "description": "USD = 600.00",
    "start": "2016-10-21",
    "end": "2016-10-21"
  }
]
```

and I want to make below json from above

```
[
  {

    "creation_datetime": "2016-10-20 12:23:29",
    "title": "Total selling currency",
    "title_two": "Date : 2016-10-20",
    "description": "DKK = 2300.00,USD = 536.66",
    "start": "2016-10-20",
    "end": "2016-10-20"
  },
  {
    "creation_datetime": "2016-10-21 13:51:28",
    "title": "Total selling currency",
    "title_two": "Date : 2016-10-21",
    "description": "USD = 600.00",
    "start": "2016-10-21",
    "end": "2016-10-21"
  }
]
```

means want to combine if same date in creation_datetime field and its to_currency in Description field

my array is below for first array json object

```
foreach ($future_sell_data as $key => $value) 
{
    $future_sell_data[$key]['title'] = "Total selling currency";
    $future_sell_data[$key]['title_two'] = "Date : " .date("Y-m-d",strtotime($value['creation_datetime']));
    $future_sell_data[$key]['description'] = $value['to_currency']." = ".$value['future_sell'];
    $future_sell_data[$key]['start'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($value['creation_datetime']));
    $future_sell_data[$key]['end'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($value['creation_datetime']));
}
```

can anyone help me how do i make second json object ?

Comment: In your sample second json, creation_datetime is not same....

Comment: sorry just a date not time

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: why is people voted down ? i don't get it ? my question is pure true , i want solution . that's why i post a question ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming that you are not considering time
2. Assuming that you have first `creation_datetime` to be considered

---

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $timestamp = $value["title_two"]; // Store the timestamp to combine similar values
    if(isset($customArr[$timestamp])) {
        $customArr[$timestamp]['description'] .= ",".$value['description'];
    } else {
        $customArr[$timestamp]['creation_datetime'] = $value['creation_datetime'];
        $customArr[$timestamp]['description'] = $value['description'];
    }
    $customArr[$timestamp]['title'] = $value['title'];
    $customArr[$timestamp]['title_two'] = $value['title_two'];
    $customArr[$timestamp]['start'] = $value['start'];
    $customArr[$timestamp]['end'] = $value['end'];
}

echo json_encode(array_values($customArr)); // timestamp is not needed for your JSON, so resetting the index
```

Output: [Check here](https://eval.in/663720)

```
[
  {
    "creation_datetime": "2016-10-20 12:23:29",
    "description": "DKK = 2300.00,USD = 536.66",
    "title": "Total selling currency",
    "title_two": "Date : 2016-10-20",
    "start": "2016-10-20",
    "end": "2016-10-20"
  },
  {
    "creation_datetime": "2016-10-21 13:51:28",
    "description": "USD = 600.00",
    "title": "Total selling currency",
    "title_two": "Date : 2016-10-21",
    "start": "2016-10-21",
    "end": "2016-10-21"
  }
]
```

Comment: hello i didn't have any field like title,title_two,description,start,end i made this custom , so i tried your solution but its gets me nulll

Comment: hello your solution is working can you please remove the DATE key in each oject ??

Comment: That's why `json_encode(array_values($customArr))` statement is for. Read the comments